# Get stored procedure name from StoredProcedureQuery

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures

After creating a stored procedure query, I later need to access the procedure name starting from the `StoredProcedureQuery` instance:

```
EntityManager em;
StoredProcedureQuery sp = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_name");

// get sp_name from sp instance
// ?
```

Is this possible using the public methods of `StoredProcedureQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following

```
if (sp instanceof ProcedureCall) {
    String procedureName = ((ProcedureCall) sp).getProcedureName();
}
```